# OpenMP inside C++ lambda function

Tags: c++, lambda, g++, openmp

Internal Compiler Error is always a bug. I will report it to g++ bug tracker.

But, is there something wrong with using OpenMP inside a lambda function, like that?

```
auto f = [&v2, &m]<typename SS>(SS &&v1)
{
    [[maybe_unused]] typedef std::remove_reference_t<SS> S1;
    resize<true>(std::forward<SS>(v1), m.columns());
    #ifdef _OPENMP
    #pragma omp declare reduction(add:S1:muladd<1>(omp_out, omp_in)) \
                initializer(resize<true>(omp_priv, omp_orig.size()))
    #endif
    if constexpr (DenseVector<T2>)
    {
        #ifdef _OPENMP
        #pragma omp parallel for reduction(add:v1) if (m.rows() * m.columns() > omp_floor)
        #endif
        for (size_t i = 0; i < v2.size(); ++i)
            if (v2[i]) muladd(std::forward<SS>(v1), m.row(i), v2[i]);
    }
    else .......
};
```

What I get is `internal compiler error: in maybe_push_to_top_level, at cp/name-lookup.cc:8256` at the reduction declaration.

But if I declare the OpenMP reduction declaration in top function, of course it is not defined inside lambda.

Comment: If you convert the whole thing from a lambda to a regular function and it compiles, there is nothing wrong and the compiler likely has a bug.

Comment: 1. OMP inside lambdas is fine. 2. Instead of `declare reduction` define `operator+` for whatever class `v1` is in and then do a normal plus reduction. 3. Still, you may be asking a bit much. How about spelling out the `muladd` and using a temporary so that the `forward` can go? Just to get it working.